# Different namespaces for main folder and subfolder

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4, php-namespaces

Is it possible to do something like:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "src/",
    "Tech\\": "src/Tech/"
}
```

As you see there is `App` namespace for `src` folder but in `src/Tech/` must be another just `Tech` namespace. I have tried it but always getting error:

```
Cannot declare class, because the name is already in use
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, although I don't know any good reason to do such thing - it just makes harder to understand namespaces structure.

The error `Cannot declare class, because the name is already in use` is probably caused by FQN ambiguity, for example if you have file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Tech\MyClass; 

$myClass =  new MyClass();
```

And you have `App\MyClass` then import for `MyClass` is ambiguous - `new MyClass()` could either mean `new \App\MyClass()` or `new \Tech\MyClass()`. You need to use aliases in this case:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Tech\MyClass as TechMyClass; 

$myClass =  new MyClass();
$myTechClass =  new TechMyClass();
```